# Web API MultipartAsync Task no result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, multipartform-data, webapi

The goal is to upload a single file to my webserver and then store it to mssql database by using multipartcontent. While the file is uploading, a progress bar should be displayed in the client (WPF application). The following code sample shows only the upload to memorystream (no database connection).

The connection from client to server works, the upload to the `MemoryStream` at server-side works and receiving receiving the percentage to client side works (section `ContinueWith` in my sample code). The problem is, the client doesn't receive the final `CreateResponse` request - like a timeout or lost connection, I am not sure because i doesn't get an error/exception. The client never receives the task final result.

WebApi:

```
public class AttachmentsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Attachments/Upload")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

        try
        {
            AttachmentUpload _resultAttachmentUpload = null;

            var _provider = new InMemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider();

            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(_provider)
                .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        throw new HttpResponseException(
                            HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                    }

                    return new AttachmentUpload()
                    {
                        FileName = _provider.Files[0].Headers.ContentDisposition
                            .FileName.Trim('\"'),
                        Size = _provider.Files[0].ReadAsStringAsync().Result
                            .Length / 1024
                    };
                });

            return Request.CreateResponse<AttachmentUpload>(HttpStatusCode.Accepted,
                _resultAttachmentUpload);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

WPF Client UploadService.cs:

```
private async Task<Attachment> UploadAttachment(AttachmentUpload uploadData,
    string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        var _encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        MultipartFormDataContent _multipartFormDataContent =
            new MultipartFormDataContent();

        _multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(
            File.ReadAllBytes(filePath))), uploadData.FileName, uploadData.FileName);
        _multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent(uploadData.Id.ToString()),
            "AttachmentId", "AttachmentId");
        _multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent(
            uploadData.Upload.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)), "AttachmentUpload",
            "AttachmentUpload");
        _multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent(
            uploadData.DocumentId.ToString()), "DocumentId", "DocumentId");
        _multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent(
            uploadData.User, _encoding), "User", "User");

        //ProgressMessageHandler is instantiate in ctor to show progressbar
        var _client = new HttpClient(ProgressMessageHandler);
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
        _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        var _requestUri = new Uri(BaseAddress + "api/Attachments/Upload");

        var _httpRequestTask = await _client.PostAsync(_requestUri,
            _multipartFormDataContent)
            .ContinueWith<AttachmentUpload>(request =>
            {
                var _httpResponse = request.Result;

                if (!_httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                var _response = _httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                AttachmentUpload _upload =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AttachmentUpload>(_response.Result);

                return _upload;
            });

        var _resultAttachment = _httpRequestTask;

        return new Attachment()
        {
            Id = _resultAttachment.Id,
            FileName = _resultAttachment.FileName,
            Comment = _resultAttachment.Comment,
            Upload = _resultAttachment.Upload,
        };

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Handle exceptions
        //file not found, access denied, no internet connection etc etc
        var tmp = e;
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The program lacks at `var _httpRequestTask = await _client.PostAsync(...)`.
The debugger never reaches the line `var _resultAttachment = _httpRequestTask;`.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't mix `await` and `ContinueWith`, the introduction of `async` / `await` effectively renders `ContinueWith` obsolete.

The reason that `var _resultAttachment = _httpRequestTask;` is never hit is because you have created a deadlock.

WPF has a synchronisation context, that ensures continuations resume on the UI thread.

In the line `AttachmentUpload _upload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AttachmentUpload>(_response.Result);`, `_response.Result` is a blocking call; it blocks the current thread, until the `Task` referenced by `_response` has completed.

The `ReadAsStringAsync` method, which generated the `Task`, will attempt to resume once the asynchronous work has completed, and the WPF synchronisation context will force it to use the UI thread, which has been blocked by `_response.Result`, hence the deadlock.

To remedy this, use the `await` keyword for **every** asynchronous call:

```
var _httpResponse = await _client.PostAsync(_requestUri, _multipartFormDataContent);

if (!_httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    throw new Exception();
}

var _response = await _httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var _resultAttachment = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AttachmentUpload>(_response);
```

You should also notice that the code is much more readable without the `ContinueWith`.